# Do successive striped candies of same direction destroy 2 layers of jelly?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

In candy crush do successive striped candies in the same line destroy two layers jelly after one detonates after the other?

so for example- 2 striped candies which both detonate vertically positioned in the same line.

Are they able to destroy 2 layers of jelly or even 1 layer of chocolate + outer coating of jelly?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the answer is no, but I haven't played in a while.

Comment: can you find a picture of this

Comment: @badp I'm actually pretty sure the answer is yes based on when I was playing it a couple weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After eventually getting this combo on a level i can confirm that it actually does take down two layers in succession. However it does so really quickly and is therefore hard to notice.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, this is **correct**.

When `Striped Candies` detonate in the same direction and are positioned in the same line/row they both would affect, they will have the following effects:

- Clear all the `Chocolate` in the row/column (only 1 `Striped Candy` needed)
- Take down **multiple layers of wrappers** (1 layer for each `Striped Candy`)
- Take down **multiple layers of jelly** (1 layer for each `Striped Candy`).

However, it will only clear **one row of candies**, no matter how many there were on that one line. This is also the main reason as to why people will not really notice that it breaks multiple layers of jelly, since only one row of candy got destroyed.

Also, when one of those black iron things are in the way, not sure what they are called, the blast will stop dead on that block, doesn't matter how many `Striped Candies` are detonating, but the black thing (just one) will be destroyed it.

**Source:**
I have seen this way too many times, including today, and have used this in clearing jelly off many levels (currently on level 316).